# How to give different groups different permissions on a specific folder?

Tags: user-management

I have two groups **"Group1"** and **"Group2"**

I have also folder **"Folder"**

I want to give **Group1** read and write permission , while **Group2** only read .

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Is there a Group 3 - no access whatsoever?

Comment: no just 2 groups

Answer (score 13):

Let me get this straight:

1. You want `group1` to have read/write access to a particular folder.
2. You want `group2` to have read-only access to that folder.
3. You don't want `others` to have read access to that folder.

By default, Linux's permission system does not allow for this. The reason is simple: for each inode there are only three bits (`rwx`) that describe permissions *for a particular group*, namely the group that owns the file/directory referred to by that inode. Any user who is not the owner nor belongs to that group automatically falls under `others`. In practice this is most often sufficient, but in some rare cases it may not be.

The good news is that Linux actually supports [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) (access control lists), which allow for a much more fine-grained access control. In order to enable ACLs, you have to add `acl` to the mount options. For instance, if the partition that contains the directory where you want to set up advanced access control is mounted like this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1  /      ext4    defaults                    0 1
```

...you would change that to:

```
/dev/sda1  /      ext4    acl,defaults                0 1
```

Then you need to remount the filesystem (e.g., `mount -o remount /dev/sda1`), or simply reboot.

Next let's make sure your folder `/path/to/folder` grants read/write access for `group1`. The permissions should look something like

```
drwxrwx---   2 owner group1      4096 Dec 14 02:42 folder
```

Additionally, you want to grant read access for `group2`, *and no access at all for `others`*. To achieve this, issue the command

```
setfacl -m g:group2:rx /path/to/folder
```

That's it. You can look into the ACL permissions of that folder later by using `getfacl`, namely:

```
getfacl /path/to/folder
```

More information here: [ACLs: Extended file-permissions](http://www.nuxified.org/blog/acls_extended_filepermissions).

Answer (score 2):

These commands should work:

```
sudo chown -R OWNER-USERNAME:GROUPNAME /PATH/TO/Folder
sudo chmod -R 664 /PATH/TO/Folder
```

This will hopefully provide read & write access to the owner and the group, and read-only access to 'Others' which should include **Group2**.

`chmod` manual page [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html).
`chown` manual page [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html).

To reset any changes so only the owner has access, run:

```
sudo chown -R OWNER-USERNAME:OWNER-USERNAME /PATH/TO/Folder
sudo chmod -R 600 /PATH/TO/Folder
```

Comment: man i don't others to have read permission

Comment: That is sort of what I  meant by my above query - should of been clearer... So you don't want others to access this? They will still need to logged as users, not just ANYONE can access it.

Comment: the owner is not in any group

Comment: The owner is usually in the group which is their username - I think it should be fine if the files are not in that group. If not, you can rectify it with `sudo chown -R OWNER-USERNAME:OWNER-USERNAME /PATH/TO/Folder; sudo chmod -R 600 /PATH/TO/Folder`